# Kotlin multiplatform type that translates to NSInteger

Tags: swift, objective-c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Using Kotlin multiplatform 1.9.10, both of these Kotlin functions:

```kotlin
fun foo(bar: NSInteger) = ...
fun fizz(buzz: integer_t) = ...
```

show up in the Objective-C header with an `int64_t` argument, not `NSInteger`. That means Swift `Int`s must be explicitly cast e.g., `foo(bar: Int64(x))`.

Obviously I can just define wrapper functions in my iOS code, but is there a Kotlin type that will compile to `NSInteger`?

Comment: I would be a little surprised if there were.